# Finding element to click in html with Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I have been struggling a bit with locating elements in HTML - using selenium/python.

I have the following which identifies a button;

```html
<button class="btn__primary--large from__button--floating" data-litms-control-urn="login-submit" type="submit" aria-label="Sign in">Sign in</button>
```

I have tried to click using;

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('btn__primary--large from__button--floating').click()
```

However, I get the error message:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".btn__primary--large from__button--floating"}
```

Any general help in finding elements would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

To click on the <kbd>Sign in</kbd> element you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button[data-litms-control-urn='login-submit'][aria-label='Sign in']").click()
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@aria-label='Sign in' and text()='Sign in']").click()
  ```

---

Ideally, to click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[data-litms-control-urn='login-submit'][aria-label='Sign in']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@aria-label='Sign in' and text()='Sign in']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 0):

There's a Space (`" "`) in your class name. You have to separate it with a dot (`.`) instead.

Instead of

`driver.find_element_by_class_name('btn__primary--large from__button--floating').click()`

Try:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('btn__primary--large.from__button--floating').click()
```

Comment: amazing, that worked! is that the case for all spaces in the html?

Comment: I think so, for all the class-names that have a space

Answer (score 0):

You can find the button with text Sign in as well.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[text()='Sign in']").click()
```