# Clicking a LinkedIn button using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, testing, automation, selenium-chromedriver

[image]

I am unable to click on the LinkedIn sign-in button. Can someone please guide me with what locator should I use? What should be the actual code.

I have tried

```
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"btn__primary--large from__button--floating").click()
```

but that doesn't work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65347241/finding-element-to-click-in-html-with-selenium-and-python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding element to click in html with Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65347241/finding-element-to-click-in-html-with-selenium-and-python)

Answer (score 1):

`CLASS_NAME` accepts single class attribute while here there are 2: `btn__primary--large` and `from__button--floating`.
To locate element based on 2 class values you can use CSS Selector or XPath, as following:

```py
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,".btn__primary--large.from__button--floating").click()
```

Or

```py
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@class='btn__primary--large from__button--floating']").click()
```